# Dashboard body does not resize with change in DT length

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

The dashboard page will not expand when more rows are shown from the DTOutput. The output is visible, but looks like it is no longer contained within the dashboard page.

```
ui <- function() { 
 dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
   mainPanel(width = 12,
             fluidRow(DTOutput(outputId = "table"))
  )))}

server <- function(input, output) {
 data <- data.frame(1:100)
 output$table <- renderDT(
  data
 )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Screenshot of issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edDqP.png)

The gray background for the dashboard page ends around row 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding some CSS to the document:

```
section.content { 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
}
```

**MWE:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
ui <- function() { 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style("section.content { overflow-y: hidden; }")),
      mainPanel(width = 12,
                fluidRow(DTOutput(outputId = "table"))
      )))}

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- data.frame(1:100)
  output$table <- renderDT(
    data
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```